# Setting up dnsmasq as a DNS and DHCP server on a LAN

Tags: dhcp, local-area-network, hostname, dnsmasq

My routers:

```
Main Router: 192.168.100.1

Second Router: 192.168.101.1
```

The `Main Router` is provided by my ISP(a modem/router combo all in one). I don't have control over its settings. Except for changing the WIFI password and SSID.

On the `Second Router`, I have control over its DNS settings.

My `Second Router's` WAN port is connected to a LAN port on the `Main router`.
I have a Debian Server with `dnsmasq` installed and connected on the `Second Router's` network with a static IP of 192.168.101.121. For those who don't know, `dnsmasq` is both a DNS and DHCP server(not enable by default).

On the `Second Router's` DNS setting, I added the `dnsmasq` DNS server(debian server) IP as the primary DNS IP and the `Main Router's` IP as the the secondary DNS IP. It works fine.

Every line in `/etc/hosts` on the Debian server is accessible on all hosts that is connected on the `Second Router's` network. That's ok.

The problem is with DHCP. As a DHCP client, you can send your hostname to the DHCP server, and it will be added to the DNS.

As the `Second Router` is already acting as a DHCP server, I can't just enable DHCP on `dnsmasq`. If I do enable it, I'll have to provide a different range(other than the second router is providing).

Only the second router is getting the hostnames, not `dnsmasq`. Has anyone run into the same problem ? Is it possible to pull the hostname entries from the second router to `dnsmasq` ? Thanks.

Comment: Disable DHCP on the second router. Since this is consumer grade it is of-topic for this site.

Comment: Yep. Works fine now. Thanks Nik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a problem, that's expected behavior. It you want to register the DHCP leases in DNS the DHCP server must do so. Your off the shelf router most probably just can't, so you will have to disable DHCP on the router and enable it in Dnsmasq.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. Now everything works fine.